# split var and create N of div with array key in html

Tags: jquery

Thanks for reading.
if we have:
var letters = 'a b c h'; // ...

how can we get this result:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="letter">a</div>
  <div class="letter">b</div>
  <div class="letter">c</div>
  <div class="letter">h</div>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

(In DOM ready) something like:

```
var letters = 'a b c h k w x'; // 7 letters (can be more...)
var char = letters.split(' ');
var nOfChars = char.length;

var divLetter = $('<div class="letter" />');

for(var char = 0; char < nOfChars; ++char) {  


    $('.box').append( divLetter );
    $('divLetter').html( char );

}
```

(Far from good, I know. please help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var letters = 'a b c h';

// don't know if you want to append to body or now, but you can fool with
// the placement of the "Wrapper" div here.
var divLetter = $('<div>',{ class: 'letter'}).appendTo('body');

$.each(letters.split(' '),function(i,e){
    $('<div>',{
        class: 'letter',
        html: e
    }).appendTo(divLetter);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jPevP/2/)

Broken down, it's the following:

1. The "letters" array is what you're accustomed too, straight forward.
2. The div is another thing you're already using, but I've used `.appendTo` to attach it to DOM. You can place this anywhere, or have the div already on the page--up to you.
3. I use jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method applied to the result of the [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) (which results in an array of letters). Each then begins iterating over each unique letter

   1. For each letter, we establish a new div
   2. We use the object parameter of jQuery to apply both the class and the body of the new element
   3. We call the [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to attach it to the original div

All said and done, we have the result you're looking for.

Comment: In this example it may be trivial, but just as a note for anyone reading this in the future: DOM operations are slow. If you are doing this type of thing with lots of "letters", you should be using a document fragment instead so there is only 1 DOM operation in the end.

Comment: I thought this one was pretty nice +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "a b c d";
var parts = string.split(" ");
for(key=0;key < parts.length;key++)
{
    $(".box").append($("<div>").addClass("letter").html(parts[key]));
}
```

Comment: Be careful, javascript's [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach#Browser_compatibility) isn't supported in quite a few browsers.

Comment: Quite a few may be over-doing it a tad, but I tend to get worked-up when it's basically and only-ie-stinks environment. ;-) But thank you for using the for and updating. -- EDIT: You should also switch to an `appendTo` just to avoid spinning up a new jQuery reference for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/sexDH/  (haha)

```
var letters = 'a b c h k w x', // 7 letters (can be more...)
    chars = letters.split(' '),
    nOfChars = chars.length,
    $divLetter = $('<div class="letter" />'),
    letterFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i=0; i<nOfChars; i++) {
    letterFragment.appendChild( $divLetter.clone().html(chars[i])[0] );
}

$('.box').append( letterFragment.cloneNode(true) );
```

Comment: ...Heheheh almost 'sexHD' :D nice one!